# Unable to access website hosted on openshift from united state

Tags: openshift

I hosted a website on jboss application server from inida. But it is not accessible from united state. I tried to ping it from india,then it is ok but from united state it is showing bad gateway. Is there any bug in openshift? Link of my testing site is http://garanci-aspiring.rhcloud.com/

Comment: I'm in the US and your site works for me.

Comment: Now, it is working because i deleted the app and recreated it. But Can you tell me why it was not working before.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issues with availability as currently, Openshift Online is hosted in the US-East region.